# How to convert SAP Table Raw Data (Data Type : LRAW) in Java

Tags: java, abap, jco

By using SAP JCO i am able to read the SAP table DBTABLOG data in to Java application.

This table has raw data (data type : LRAW) in one of the columns, it is impossible to understand the content.

How can we convert this RAW data in to readable format in Java ? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary` worked for me in the similar situation.

Also, we can use java `String` constructor to convert the bytes to readable String too.

`String readableStr = new String(bytes)`

or

Use with Character Encoding

`String readableStr = new String(bytes, "UTF-16")`

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh.
I will try this.